# Test for unification in Oz

Tags: pattern-matching, unification, oz, mozart

What I want to do is, test if a certain expression unifies with another in Oz.

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
fun {UnifyP A B}
  ...
end
```

that can return `true` when `A` can be unified to `B` and false else.

I want to use it to do a specific pattern matching (i.e. filter  lists by a specific pattern).

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Is `B` a constant pattern or a value that is computed at runtime?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had forgotten about this question since I continued doing something else. 

B is constant. I.e, `A` is `point(X Y)` and `B` is `point(0 0)`.